# Alter chrome developer toolbar list / shown panels

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was recently using the dev tools in Firefox and noticed you could turn on and off certain menus (styles, network, storage, etc.) . When back in the Chrome dev tools, I looked for the same check-boxes / functionality to no avail.

A bit of googling got me no where, nor any answers here. I've read that I could go and manually alter the dev tools in Chrome / make plugins / etc, but was wondering if I just overlooked this feature or if someone has already made this wheel?

Thanks.

Edit: pictures

[highlighted firefox dev tool settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VPO8.png)

[firefox dev tools with added toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa3Jq.png)

Comment: Hello, I'm the technical writer on the Chrome DevTools team. I don't think we have this feature. But I'm also not sure I completely understand what you're looking for. Can you update your question to include some screenshots from the Firefox DevTools?

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking a look. I've added a pair of pictures. Basically there are checkboxes in Firefox that you can click to add / removes tools. I think chrome calls them panels -> Network, Console, Application, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. We don't have this feature. I'll create a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the Chrome DevTools technical writer. This feature doesn't exist. I created a feature request here: https://crbug.com/888667

If you want this feature, star the request. The more stars a request gets, the more likely it is that the team will implement the feature.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go do that.